# what are benefits of meteor's phonegap wrapper vs a native app with a webview?

Tags: cordova, meteor, phonegap-plugins

Building with phonegap can be a flaky furstrating process. What are the actual benefits of using phonegap layers vs. just a plain native app which opens a webview?

I understand MDG's cordova build added some caching on parts of the app JS code but since a new meteor release updates the whole single JS file each time, this wouldn't be much of a benefit. Maybe some image caching? Does the local webserver do anything?

If you are using native APIs from JS then the cordova bridge is of some use.

But by using a plain native app, you get access to all the build stability, and it's fairly trivial to just open a webview. A JS bridge opens access to any native APIs fairly easily too.

There are various phonegap plugins, but most of these are wrappers around native SDKs anyway, introducing nothing more than leaky problems (eg getting facebook login to work with phonegap and then meteor)

I've built a native android wrapper which is ~1MB, uses latest chrome webview, and can be extended with any native features easily.

I'd like to know more what the benefits of using phonegap are, especially since MDG put time into it.

update: meteor forums discussion
https://forums.meteor.com/t/cordova-benefits-vs-custom-native-wrapper/5356

Answer (score 2):

Meteor uses Cordova for its wrapper amid a few amendments:

- A web server so your app is accessed from http://meteor.local instead of file://www/...
- An autoupdater that updates the files from the server via a hot code push.
- A few modifications to allow the login with facebook/twitter/google to popup a UIWebView to log in as a better UI alternative to opening the browser. This used to be really bad issue.

The web server allows you to use typical iron routing for your app. You can route to `/`, `/page/:id` instead of `index.html`. This makes it significantly easier to develop "hybrid apps" & to use URI schemes locally.

There are also a few modifications set to use `app-config.js` to generate a config.xml.

So in addition to these for the phonegap wrapper itself you get the typical Meteor style app where you can use Meteor code and packages, such as HTTP.

Apart from this the functionality is nearly the same as with cordova. You can add cordova packages into your meteor app using `meteor add cordova:<cordova package>@<package_version>`

There are also a few interesting developments such as the ability to use WKWebView on iOS which is not currently possible on cordova due to the reliance on `file://` urls. WKWebView uses significantly less resources over a UIWebView and gives out more performance. Quite useful on a mobile device.

Comment: 1) i usually just access the remote server by http and not mix local files? (2)  how is this different from if a webview was running the server? (3) logging in via a webview is bad UX since the password is not stored. a native login is a far better option. So I don't see much benefit from these three? I'm not sure i see your point about hybrid apps tho, you mean mixing local file URIs to call a remote http URI? otherwise it's just a normal deployed meteor app you're accessing which is of course using whatever routes you want.

Comment: @dcsan What if you don't have an internet connection so you can't access the remote server? The cordova used to be closer to what you describe without the http server on the original betas but the experience was terrible, the http server was a really good decision on their part. The webview login was only once since then you would be/are logged in for good, till you log out. It's very difficult to built an app for meteor using routes like `/index.html` without access to dynamic routing.

Comment: @dcsan With hybrid apps you can build your meteor app to run on http://localhost:3000, and you can expect it will behave the same way on your mobile device. If you build for cordova you can only expect it will work under the `file://` protocol and can't be used on a web server. If you build an accompanying web app you will have twice the work.

Comment: @dcsan Concering the UIWebView login the experience before used to be a full screen UIWebView (in cordova) or none at all since cordova does not support popups. When it was a full screen experience it used to be a white screen for 10-20 seconds (mobile 3G isn't instant) and the UX with this was nearly the top complaint on meteor-talk at the time. Here is one of the threads discussing the issue: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/z-OlDmUI_8E. There are also a few packages on atmosphere trying to solve it too, albeit poorly.

Comment: re /index.html this is for some type of hybrid with both local files and http served files?

Comment: I still don't see many benefits with this, so it's more of a discussion, started here:   https://forums.meteor.com/t/cordova-benefits-vs-custom-native-wrapper/5356

Comment: @dcsan I've used both styles. The best I would advise you is to try to build a cordova app and see the difference. The /`index.html` routing issue is a big dealbreaker. You can't do something like `/blogs/the-post-about-this` on cordova. No, index.html is the default file in a cordova application. `/` supported & routing/pushstate isn't supported well.

Comment: i'm not comparing vanilla phonegap with MDGs, i'm comparing it with a native Android wrapper app, not using phonegap *at all*.